# CakePHP: Distinguish between regular http and REST calls

Tags: rest, cakephp, methods, view, call

I want the same Controller routines to serve both regular web-based page loads as well as REST calls. I have REST handling set-up in my routes.php:

```
// Setup REST Handling
Router::mapResources( '<ControllerName>' );
Router::parseExtensions();
```

Let's take for example, the **add()** method - how do I distinguish inside this method how the call is being made?

To elaborate on the issue:

```
public function add() {
    $status = array();
    if( $this->request->is( 'post' ) ) {
            // Read POST body
            $entityBody = file_get_contents( 'php://input' );
    }
}
```

As you can see in the above code, I'm detecting POST requests and will deal with the request accordingly. What I need to figure is whether the post data is coming from a REST call of from a web-form. If the data comes from a web-form, it'll be in the request->data array whereas for a REST call, it'll be in XML form.

I'll deal with the data accordingly and dish out an appropriate response.

Thanks.

Comment: If web-form requests are coming from different domain than the REST requests, you could inspet `$this->referer()` if it matches. If the origin for both types of POST requests are identical (same domain), you could add some extra param to REST request, e.g. `rest => true`. Or you could try check request headers (e.g. content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded for web-form). Not sure if there is some better way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the CakeRequest object, see [the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#cakerequest), works the same as with post.

```
$this->request->is('put');
```

- is('get') Check to see if the current request is a GET.
- is('put') Check to see if the current request is a PUT.
- is('post') Check to see if the current request is a POST.
- is('delete') Check to see if the current request is a DELETE.